# how to track the time taken for a move operation from one folder to another in linux

Tags: time, move

how to track the time taken for a move operation from one folder to another in linux
I have been performing a move operation like the sample below. I would like to know how much time in seconds does it take for the whole move operation to complete.

```
[root@servername /]# mv /source/TEST/perf/delta1/* /destination/TEST/perf/delta2/
[root@servername /]#

[root@servername /]# time mv /source/TEST/perf/delta1/* /destination/TEST/perf/delta2/
mv: cannot stat `/source/TEST/perf/delta1/*': No such file or directory

real    0m0.010s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.000s
```

When I set the time parameter in the front of the move command, the same command doesnt work with that syntax for some reason. Can some one help with an option that would solve this requirement.

Comment: It didn't work the second time because the first command moved all of the files out of that directory, so the pattern doesn't match anything anymore.

Comment: Do you want to include the time taken to expand the wildcard to find all the files to move? That's done by the shell before executing the `time` command.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your command into a script like this

filename: `timer_script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

start_time=$(date +%s)

# your command you want to time
mv /source/TEST/perf/delta1/* /destination/TEST/perf/delta2/

end_time=$(date +%s)
(( elapsed = end_time - start_time ))
echo "time taken: $elapsed seconds"
```

to run it:

```
chmod +x timer_script.sh
```

then

```
./timer_script.sh
```

Comment: Dear the_velour_fog,

Comment: Dear the_velour_fog, Thank you so much for your response. Very helpful.